# Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: coin is not defined

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет!
Пытаюсь получить курс криптовалюты usd-coin, но вылезает ошибка. Весь код снизу

```
fetch('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=usd-coin%2CBitcoin%2CEthereum%2CTether%2CRipple%2Cbinancecoin%2C&vs_currencies=usd&include_24hr_change=true&precision=2')
    .then(function (resp) {return resp.json() })
    .then (function (data){
      console.log(data)
        document.getElementById('bitcoin').innerHTML = data.bitcoin.usd
        document.getElementById('ethereum').innerHTML = data.ethereum.usd
        document.getElementById('tether').innerHTML = data.tether.usd
        document.getElementById('ripple').innerHTML = data.ripple.usd
        document.getElementById('bnb').innerHTML = data.binancecoin.usd
        document.getElementById('usdc').innerHTML = data.usd-coin.usd
    })
```

Как мне кажется ошибка в -, может быть можно ее чем-нибудь заменить

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: `data['usd-coin'].usd`

Answer (score 0):

Сделал так, все заработало

```
data['usd-coin'].usd
```